# ¿Como evito que un usuario acapare un reservación el mismo día?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo aquí.
Y tengo una duda, tengo un programa de citas médicas donde un usuario puede reservar una cita médica para el día que el medico tenga disponible de acuerdo a su agenda, hasta allí todo bien. Los usuarios no pueden reservar horas medicas ya ocupadas, pero tengo un problema.

Resulta que un mismo usuario puede acaparar la agenda del día si así lo desea, es decir; si para el dia 26/04 tengo las siguientes horas disponibles: 8:30, 9:00, 9:30. 10:00, 10:30 11:00 y 11:30, el usuario puede acaparar todas esas horas ¿cómo evito eso?

```
public static function getRepeated($pacient_id,$medic_id,$date_at,$time_at){
       $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where pacient_id=$pacient_id and medic_id=$medic_id and date_at=\"$date_at\" and time_at=\"$time_at\" and status_id=1";
       $query = Executor::doit($sql);
       return Model::one($query[0],new ReservationData());
   }
```

En el codigo adjunto se pueden ver como evito con SQL que los usuarios puedan repetir una reserva ya tomada, pero no evita que se hagan reservas consecutivas para el mismo día en diferentes horas disponibles.

```
$rx = ReservationData::getRepeated($_POST["pacient_id"],$_POST["medic_id"],$_POST["branch_id"],$_POST["date_at"],$_POST["time_at"]);


//if(true){
if($rx==null){
$r = new ReservationData();
$r->no = $_POST["no"];
$r->title = $_POST["title"];
$r->note = $_POST["note"];
$r->pacient_id = $_POST["pacient_id"];
$r->medic_id = $_POST["medic_id"];
$r->date_at = $_POST["date_at"];
$r->time_at = $_POST["time_at"];
$r->user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$r->branch_id = $_POST["branch_id"];

$r->status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
$r->payment_id = $_POST["payment_id"];
$r->price = $_POST["price"];
$r->sick = $_POST["sick"];
$r->symtoms = $_POST["symtoms"];
$r->medicaments = $_POST["medicaments"];


$r->add();
```

En este codigo se puede ver cómo funciona la funcion getRepeated.

Espero haber sido claro y no haberme enredado explicando. Agradecería si pudieran ayudarme.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. En mi opinión, la respuesta a tu pregunta actual es: busca si hay otra reserva del mismo usuario para el mismo día, y en caso de haberla, le niegas le nueva reserva. Se esperaría que tú, como programador, sepas convertir eso en código. Si al intentar hacerlo encuentras algún problema, entonces tu pregunta debiera ser sobre ese problema específico que tienes, y tu código, el que ya has logrado producir para implementar esa solución. Te invito a leer [ask].

Comment: Tal como te dijo @jachguate haz una consulta similar pero para el dia (ignorando la hora) para saber si el usuario ya hizo una reserva para ese dia.

Comment: No sé cómo tienes tus tablas, pero es evidente que aquí hay en 1er lugar **un error de diseño**. Si 1 usuario no puede reservar más de una cita x día, entonces la tabla que gestiona las citas debería tener una restricción `UNIQUE` en la columna de la fecha, así, por más que el usuario intente acaparar un día entero no podrá. Dicho eso, es claro que debes mejorar el código, por ejemplo, revisando, antes de mostrar los horarios disponibles, si ese usuario ya tiene una hora reservada ese día, en cuyo caso le indicarás que ya tiene hora reservada, y dándole la posibilidad de cambiar si es preciso.

Comment: @jachguate tenías razón, ya lo resolví. Me estaba calentando la cabeza por algo bastante simple la verdad.